# imputing missing values from respective column

Tags: r, function, missing-data

I'm trying to fill in the missing values randomly sampled from the column. For instance, for variable "apple" the data looks like (1, 2, 3, NA) then I want NA to be imputed randomly from (1,2,3). I've come up with the following code, but I'm trying to make it so that R imputes from the respective column, not the whole data set

```
random.imp <- function (a){
missing <- is.na(a)
n.missing <- sum(missing)
a.obs <- a[!missing]
imputed <- a
imputed[missing] <- sample (a.obs, n.missing, replace=TRUE)
return (imputed)
}
train.num<- random.imp (train.num)
```

I think there is something wrong with the code after `sample`, and any comments would really help!

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT* updated to work on a dataframe

```
# MAKE THE DATA
train.num<-data.frame(var=sample(c("a","b","v","h","i"),10,TRUE),
                      c1=sample(c(NA,1,4,8),10,T),
                      c2=sample(c(NA,2,3,0),10,T),
                      c3=sample(c(NA,5,9,11),10,T))

# CALL THE FUNCTION
random.imp <- function (a){

  n<-length(a[is.na(a)])
  a[is.na(a)]<-sample(unique(a[!is.na(a)]),n,TRUE)
  return(a)

}

# USE APPLY TO RUN THE FUNCTION COLWISE (in this case for columns 2-4)
train.num[,2:4]<-apply(train.num[,2:4],2,function(x)random.imp(x))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it yielded the same result - it doesn't seem to be imputing from the column, but from the whole data set! For instance, for the data I checked, the original data was (1, 2, 0, NA) but after running the code it was (1, 2, 2000, NA) (2000 was placed from some other column).

Comment: OK, in that case you need to use apply to run the function colwise - code edited above

Answer (score 0):

```
random.imp <- function(a){
  a[is.na(a)] <- sample(x = a[!is.na(a)], size = sum(is.na(a)), replace = TRUE)
  return(a)
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 3, 4, NA), y = c(NA, 6, NA, 5, NA))
df
#    x  y
# 1  1 NA
# 2 NA  6
# 3  3 NA
# 4  4  5
# 5 NA NA

df[] <- lapply(df, random.imp)
df
#   x y
# 1 1 5
# 2 1 6
# 3 3 6
# 4 4 5
# 5 1 6
```